# There is no redirection after redirect_to @contract

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create new payment

```
def new
    @contract = Contract.find(session[:contract_id])
    # Register card for user
    @card_preregistration = MangoPay::CardRegistration.create({
        UserId: current_user.mangopay_id,
        Currency: "EUR",
        CardType: "CB_VISA_MASTERCARD"
      })
    session[:card_id] = @card_preregistration['Id']
    locals card_reg: @card_preregistration
  end
```

pass all data to url payment server with ajax.

**register_card.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#payment-form').submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()  
    $this = $(this)

    mangoPay.cardRegistration.init
      cardRegistrationURL: $("#CardRegistrationURL").val()
      preregistrationData: $("#PreregistrationData").val()
      accessKey: $("#AccessKey").val()

    cardData = {
      cardNumber: $("#card_number").val()
      cardExpirationDate: $("#card_expiration_date").val()
      cardCvx: $("#cardCvx").val()
    }

    mangoPay.cardRegistration.sendDataWithAjax(
      # URL to capture response
      "http://site:8080/finialize",
      # Card data
      cardData,
      # Result Ajax callback
      (data) ->
        #console.log(data)
      # Error Ajax callback
      (xhr, status, error) -> 
        alert("Payment error : " + xhr.responseText + " (" + status + " - " + error + ")")

    )
```

After run method **payments/finialize_payment**:

```
def finialize_payment
    @contract = Contract.find(session[:contract_id])  
  begin
    card_registration = MangoPay::CardRegistration.update(session[:card_id], {
      RegistrationData: "data=#{params['data']}",
      Tag: "custom tag"
    })

    if card_registration['Status'] != "VALIDATED" 
      flash[:error] = "Cannot create card. Payment has not been created."
    end
    #get created virtual card object
    card = MangoPay::Card.fetch(card_registration['CardId'])

    # create temporary wallet for user
    wallet = MangoPay::Wallet.create({
      Owners: [card_registration['UserId']],
      Currency: 'EUR',
      Description: 'Temporary wallet for payment demo'
    })
    # create pay-in CARD DIRECT
    payIn = MangoPay::PayIn::Card::Direct.create({
      CardId: card['Id'], 
      CreditedWalletId: wallet['Id'],
      CardType: 'CB_VISA_MASTERCARD',
      Culture: 'FR',
      AuthorId: card_registration['UserId'],
      ReturnURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      DebitedFunds: { Amount: @contract.amount.to_i, Currency: 'EUR' },
      Fees: {Amount: 0, Currency: 'EUR'},
      #payment type as CARD
      PaymentDetails: {CardType: card['CardType'], CardId: card['Id']},
      #execution type as DIRECT
      SecureModeReturnURL: 'http://test.site'
    })
     #if created Pay-in object has status SUCCEEDED it's mean that all is fine
     if payIn['Status'] == 'SUCCEEDED'
        redirect_to @contract
        flash[:notice] = "Pay-In has been created successfully."        
     else
       # if created Pay-in object has status different than SUCCEEDED 
        # that occurred error and display error message
        flash[:notice] = "Pay-In has been created with status: #{payIn['Status']}"
     end

  rescue MangoPay::ResponseError => e 
    flash[:error] = " Code: #{ e.code } Message: #{ e.message }"
  end

  end
```

**If payIn status successed should be redirect_to @contract
But the page is not reloaded. Console display render contracts/show:**

```
Started GET "/finialize?data=fq7ztNH9ztspcfzpUGj0_V3LhW5PKCuOSJd3CnWIdMfxq6ij__ENfQKBL_aHSaveqk7FwpB65dRgiot-92qsK0CUwTIbKLWEd9f-weFksTiJZU28-RIz5QNUh_6FYHM7_uh-M22NjZ6dU5YsJBBYuA" for 10.240.0.195 at 2016-08-02 11:50:35 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.0.195! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PaymentsController#finialize_payment as */*
  Parameters: {"data"=>"fq7ztNH9ztspcfzpUGj0_V3LhW5PKCuOSJd3CnWIdMfxq6ij__ENfQKBL_aHSaveqk7FwpB65dRgiot-92qsK0CUwTIbKLWEd9f-weFksTiJZU28-RIz5QNUh_6FYHM7_uh-M22NjZ6dU5YsJBBYuA"}
  Contract Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts" WHERE "contracts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Redirected to http://localhost.io:8080/contracts/e7834c9a
Completed 302 Found in 2773ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)


Started GET "/contracts/e7834c9a" for 10.240.1.18 at 2016-08-02 11:50:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.1.18! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ContractsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"e7834c9a"}
```

How correct redirect_to @contract, if payIn status is Successed? Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would let the server return some sort of json object to indicate if the finalize method went well. With this json payload from the server you could then let the javascript dictate which page it should redirect to.

Comment: I dont know how. I use standart js library from mangopay: *mangoPay.cardRegistration.sendDataWithAjax*